# Using the word 'set' Error

Tags: objective-c

In my .h file I have these methods declared:

```
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName;
-(void) setEmail: (NSString *) theEmail;
-(void) vsetAge: (NSString *) theAge;
-(void) vsetGender: (NSString *) theGender;
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName andEmail: (NSString *) theEmail;
-(void) setAge: (NSString *) theAge andGender: (NSString *) theGender;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name, *email, *age, *gender;
```

and in the .m

```
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName {
    if (name != theName) {
    name = [NSString stringWithString:theName];
    }
}
-(void) setEmail: (NSString *) theEmail {
    if (email != theEmail) {
    email = [NSString stringWithString:theEmail];
    }
}
-(void) vsetAge: (NSString *) theAge {
        self.age = theAge;
}
-(void) vsetGender: (NSString *) theGender {
    self.gender = theGender;
}
```

*I didnt add in the other methods in this question*

My question is, using setName, setEmail works perfectly. But as soon as I created 2 new methods, Age and Gender I kept getting an error whenever I used the word set, therefore i just added In a random letter 'v' infont and it works. Any explanation why setName / setEmail works but setAge does not? Thank you

Comment: Why are you explicitly declaring the "set" methods in the .h file? They will be declared implicitly by the properties.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying

Comment: @rmaddy says: Declared properties (`@property`)  are *method declarations*. It already declares the methods `setName:` pp. There is no reason to repeat the declaration explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the code you posted is unnecessary. Don't explicitly declare the "setter" methods for your properties in the .h file.

And your explicit "setter" method implementations in the .m file are unnecessary as well.

Your .h can just be:

```
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName andEmail: (NSString *) theEmail;
-(void) setAge: (NSString *) theAge andGender: (NSString *) theGender;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name, *email, *age, *gender;
```

And in the .m, get rid of all 4 of those methods.

If you have used any `@synthesize` statements in the .m, get rid of them too.

On a side note, using `stringWithString:` in such cases is pointless. Instead of something like:

```
name = [NSString stringWithString:theName];
```

just do:

```
name = theName;
```

Comment: Oh ok, so what you're saying if lets say for the @property name, I don't declare the setter method in my .h file but in the .m file can I say 

-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName {
    self.name = theName
}

Comment: You don't need any code in the .m file for the "setter" method. By default, when you do `@property name;` in the .h, you implicitly get both the setter and getter methods automatically. You don't need to declare the methods in the .h or implement the methods in the .m. Of course you can provide your own custom implementations if you have a special reason to do so. But from the code you posted, you have no reason to.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, Ill change it to that! Also, would you know why the regular setAge didnt work but vsetAge did?

Comment: Not really since you didn't post the actual complete error message and point out where it actually occurred.

Comment: Your problem is the fact that your implementation of `setAge:` is `self.age = theAge;`. That is causing infinite recursion. Because that is really `[self setAge:theAge];`. So it simply keeps calling itself forever until it crashes. You would need `_age = theAge;` instead of `self.age = theAge;`.

Comment: ahh, Only when i setting 2 things should i use the self. ?

Comment: Always use `self.propertyName` when using a property except inside your own custom "setter" method for the given property. But again, in this case, you have no need to be explicitly implementing any of the "setter" methods for these properties.